# Normalization for a free Dirac plane wave

Tags: dirac-equation, dirac-matrices, normalization, plane-wave

I've recently come about the free plane wave solutions to the Dirac equation, and i'm having a hard time proving that the normalization factor $n$ is
$$n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m(m+\omega)}}$$
Where $\omega$ is the energy.

The information that i've used to try and prove it is that
$$\bar{u}_ru_s=\delta_{rs}$$
(Im focusing on the positive frequency) $u_s$ is $u_s(p=0)$ where 
$$u_s(p)=n(\gamma^\mu p_\mu+m){u}_s$$
Since $\bar{u}_ru_s$ is lorentz invariant that means it is the same in all reference frame so
$$\bar{u}_r(p)u_s(p)=\delta_{rs}$$
Where $\bar{u}_r(p)=u^\dagger_r(p)\gamma^0$. This means that
$$\bar{u}_r(p)u_s(p)=n^2[(\gamma^\mu p_\mu+m){u}_r]^\dagger\gamma^0(\gamma^\mu p_\mu+m){u}_s$$
$$n^2[(\gamma^\mu p_\mu+m){u}_r]^\dagger\gamma^0(\gamma^\mu p_\mu+m){u}_s=\delta_{rs}$$
$$n^2([\gamma^\mu]^\dagger p_\mu+m){u}_r^\dagger\gamma^0(\gamma^\mu p_\mu+m){u}_s=\delta_{rs}$$
And using the definition for the Dirac adjoint 
$$n^2([\gamma^\mu]^\dagger p_\mu+m)(\gamma^\mu p_\mu+m)\bar{u}_r{u}_s=\delta_{rs}$$
But $\bar{u}_r(p)u_s(p)=\delta_{rs}$ by the previous definition
$$n^2([\gamma^\mu]^\dagger p_\mu+m)(\gamma^\mu p_\mu+m)\delta_{rs}=\delta_{rs}$$
This means that
$$n^2([\gamma^\mu]^\dagger p_\mu+m)(\gamma^\mu p_\mu+m)=1$$
$$([\gamma^\mu]^\dagger p_\mu+m)(\gamma^\mu p_\mu+m)=n^{-2}$$
Changing the second bracket $\mu\rightarrow\nu$ and when I expand I get
$$[\gamma^\mu]^\dagger \gamma^\nu p_\mu p_\nu + m \gamma^\nu p_\nu + m[\gamma^\mu]^\dagger p_\mu + m^2=n^{-2}$$
$$[\gamma^0]^\dagger \gamma^0 p_0 p_0 + [\gamma^i]^\dagger \gamma^j p_i p_j + m \gamma^\nu p_\nu + m[\gamma^\mu]^\dagger p_\mu + m^2=n^{-2}$$
$p_0=\omega$, $[\gamma^0]^\dagger = \gamma^0$ and $[\gamma^i]^\dagger = -\gamma^i$
$$\gamma^0 \gamma^0 \omega^2 - \gamma^i\gamma^j p_i p_j + m \gamma^\nu p_\nu + m[\gamma^\mu]^\dagger p_\mu + m^2=n^{-2}$$
Since $\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu = \eta^{\mu\nu}$ where $\eta^{\mu\nu}=(+1,-1,-1,-1)$
$$\omega^2 - [-p^2] + m \gamma^\nu p_\nu + m[\gamma^\mu]^\dagger p_\mu + m^2=n^{-2}$$
$$\omega^2 + p^2 + m \gamma^\nu p_\nu + m[\gamma^\mu]^\dagger p_\mu + m^2=n^{-2}$$
We can do the same trick of expanding the repeated indices for $m[\gamma^\mu]^\dagger p_\mu$ and $m \gamma^\nu p_\nu$
$$\omega^2 + p^2 + m\gamma^0 p_0  + m \gamma^k p_k + m[\gamma^0]^\dagger p_0 + m[\gamma^k]^\dagger p_k + m^2=n^{-2}$$
Evaluating the hermitian adjoints we get
$$\omega^2 + p^2 + m\gamma^0 \omega  + m \gamma^k p_k + m\gamma^0 \omega - m\gamma^k p_k + m^2=n^{-2}$$
$$\omega^2 + p^2 + m^2 + 2m\gamma^0 \omega=n^{-2}$$
Using $p^2 + m^2 = \omega^2$
$$2\omega^2 + 2m\gamma^0 \omega=n^{-2}$$
$$2\omega(\omega + m\gamma^0)=n^{-2}$$
This means that
$$n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega(\omega + m\gamma^0)}}$$
The problem is that I cannot get rid of the $\gamma^0$ and I get a $\omega$ in place of the $m$
If you need more information I was learning from the video link below

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-m23BxI9vSc&list=PLSpklniGdSfSsk7BSZjONcfhRGKNa2uou&index=5

It's a video by Deiterich Labs

I have no formal education in physics so I rely on videos like his and I also might be missing something obvious.

Thanks

Comment: Where does the equation $u_s(p)=n(\gamma^\mu p_\mu+m){u}_s$ come from? In general, it is false; the correct expression is $u_s(p)=D(\Lambda_p)u_s(0)$, where $\Lambda_p$ is the Lorentz transformation that takes you from $p=0$ to arbitrary $p$. Also, $D$ is the spinor representation of the Lorentz group. (See e.g. section 38 in Srednicki's free book online). Your equation for $u_s(p)$ is wrong, unless I misunderstood your notation. Would you please clarify this? Thanks.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I got the equation from the link at the bottom, it's a video by Dietrich Labs.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Hope this clarifies where it comes from. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-m23BxI9vSc&list=PLSpklniGdSfSsk7BSZjONcfhRGKNa2uou&index=5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanna calculate $$\bar{u}_s(p)u_s(p) = n^2u^\dagger_s (\gamma^{\nu \dagger } p_\nu + m)\gamma_0 (\gamma^\mu p_\mu + m) u_s.$$ This look different than what you have above the line where you used the Dirac adjoint. Either I don’t understand what you did there or you have a mistake. Next I use that $\gamma^{\nu \dagger} = \gamma_0 \gamma^\nu \gamma_0$,and expand the brackets, $$\bar{u}_s(p)u_s(p)  =n^2  \bar{u} (2m^2 + 2m \gamma^\nu p_\nu) u, \\ = 2m n^2(m + \omega - u^{\dagger}_s \gamma^i u_s p_i ),$$ where I used the fact that  $\gamma_0 u_s = u_s$, $u^\dagger_s \gamma_0 = u_s^\dagger$ and that $p^0 = \omega$.  Now what is left is to show that  $ u^{\dagger}_s \gamma^i u_s = 0$, this is not hard to see since, $$   u^{\dagger}_s  \gamma^i u_s  = u^{\dagger}_s  \gamma^i \gamma_0 u_s = -  u^{\dagger}_s \gamma_0 \gamma^i u_s = -  u^{\dagger}_s  \gamma^i u_s = 0.$$  If I haven’t made any mistakes, this proves that $$    \bar{u}_s(p)u_s(p)  = 2m(m + \omega )n^2 $$

Comment: How did you get $2m^2$ because I managed to get $2\omega^2$

Comment: I think that was my mistake, what did I do wrong there?

Comment: One of the $2m^2$ come from $m^2 \bar{u} u$, the other come from $\bar{u}(\gamma^\nu p_\nu)^2 u$. This is also another typo, or a mistake that I noticed in your question. $\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu \neq \eta^{\mu \nu}$, rather, $\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\} = 2\eta^{\mu \nu}$. Using this you can show that $(\gamma^\nu p_\nu)^2 = p^\nu p_\nu = m^2$. Hope this helps. It's kinda impressive you having no formal education in physics and still choosing to bang your head against these kind of "boring" calculations!

Comment: Thank you, so much, I've been struggling with that for a few days :)

Comment: You are welcome! :)